# Asymptotic bi-infinite geodesics in CAT($-1$) space coincides

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic, metric-geometry

Suppose $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:(-\infty,\infty)\to (X,d)$ be two bi-infinite geodesic such that $d(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))<K$ for all $t$.
Here $(X,d)$ is a CAT$(-1)$ space. Then Image($\gamma_1$)=Image($\gamma_2$).

Before posting I have seen that the solution to my problem would follow from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949287/779382) but there is no answer to it.
I tried to use the hyperbolic law of cosines to estimate the distance $d(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$ to make it arbitrarily small so that it finally tends to zero as $t$ goes to $\infty$.

Please help! Some hints would help me as well. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see a question in your post. A hint: Think about the flat strip theorem for CAT(0) spaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have edited my question .I wanted to see Image of two geodesics coincides

Comment: Ok, are you familiar with the flat strip theorem for CAT(0) spaces? What book are you reading?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it I am reading "metric spaces of non positive curvature" by B-H

Comment: OK, then did you consider applying it in the case at hand?

Comment: But how does it help ? If I can prove the other problem which I have mentioned then I can say by Convexity that the two geodesics coincides @MoisheKohan

Comment: In order to apply flat strip theorem I must have the distance between geodesics goes to zero

Comment: No, all you need is the distance between the geodesics to be bounded (in both directions), you are misreading the result.

Comment: Applying Flat strip what do I get? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Think: What kind of flat strips a CAT(-1) space can possibly contain?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it. This may be silly but i am not getting it @MoisheKohan

Comment: 1. Do you know the definition of a flat strip? 2. Do you know the definition of a CAT(-1) space? 3. Can you prove that  the Euclidean plane is not a CAT(-1) space? 4. Can the same proof be used for a  flat strip replacing the Euclidean plane?

Comment: Yes, I got it! I was stuck with this problem for quite some time. Thanks a lot, @MoisheKohan for this useful sequence of hints. But how does one solve the other problem that I have mentioned in the question, there I don't have a flat strip?

Comment: Can I write down an answer below following your hint @MoisheKohan

Comment: Your are welcome to write your own solution, that's why I gave you the hints. I did not read the other question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have written down an answer following your hint. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is the culmination of Moishe Kohan's comments and hints which he has provided in the comments. Thanks!

---

Let us call the convex set generated by the image of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ by $S$.

$S$ with subspace metric is CAT$(-1)$ as it is a convex subspace.

By the flat strip theorem $S$ is isometric to $[0, D]\times \mathbb{R}$, where $D$ is the Hausdorff distance between the images of two geodesics, hence $D\ge0$.

> Note:  For 'Flat Strip Theorem' refer to [Metric Spaces of Non-Positive](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/bridsonhaefligerx.pdf) Curvature by  André Haefliger and Martin Bridson page 182. Also note that a CAT($-1$) space is CAT($0$).

Suppose $D>0$ then we can consider a non-degenerate triangle $\Delta$ in $S$.
Then by the conclusion of the flat strip theorem sum of the angles of $\Delta$ is $\pi$.
But $S$ being CAT$(-1)$ has sum of the angles of $\Delta$ strictly less than $\pi$. This is not possible!

Hence we must have $D=0$ therefore Image$(\gamma_1)$=Image$(\gamma_2)$

Comment: Right...........